# Beautifulsoup returning empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url = "https://www.pararius.com/apartments/amsterdam"


page = requests.get(url)



soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#za sve sekcije koje imaju class name listing-search-item vadim ih u list
lists= soup.find_all('section', class_="listing-search-item")


with open('housing.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    
    header = ['Title', 'Location', 'Price', 'Area']
    thewriter.writerow(header)
    for list in lists:

        title = list.find('a', class_="listing-search-item__link listing-search-item__link--title").text.replace('\n', '')
        location = list.find('div', class_="entity-description-itemCaption").text.replace('\n', '')
        price = list.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__price").text.replace('\n', '')
        area = list.find('li', class_="illustrated-features__item--surface-area").text.replace('\n', '')
        info = [title, location, price, area]
        thewriter.writerow(info)

print(lists)
```

So, when I want to check the output in the terminal I do not get any data. Also the csv. file that is generated has only a header written on it.  I am a beginner in python and web scraping. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably check what you got in `page.content`. It might not be what you expect, especially if the site dynamically loads most of its contents.

Comment: this site have protection - Checking your browser before accessing www.pararius.com. This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly. Please allow up to 5 seconds… So u need set cookies or use selenium

Comment: or try this lib - https://pypi.org/project/pararius/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that on first loading of this site, your browser will be check and it means you can't access to the page source that you need with an HTTP library. In this cases, you should use Web Browser to load the HTML.
For this task, you can use Web Browser Automation tools that are available in Python.

I recommend `Selenium` and `Playwright` for Python.